# No sound on touch button

Tags: android, button, touch, audio

If I use:

```
    final Button btnNught = (Button) findViewById(R.id.night);
    btnNught.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            btnNught.setPressed(true);
        }
    });
```

And if I click on button I listen click sound, but if I use:

```
    btnNught.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (btnNught.isPressed()) {
                btnNught.setPressed(false);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                btnNught.setPressed(true);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I do not listen any sound on touch.
Where I made mistake?

Edit:
I want to create button like togglebutton with two state: pressed and non-pressed with two different colors of course (normal-light gray non pressed and green when pressed).

In this case (above), when I touch button I do not listen any sound, but if I use onClick method I listen 'click' sound. 
How can I get 'click' or 'touch' sound when I use onTouch method?

Answer (score 6):

Doing this works for me:

```
btnNught.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
btnNught.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||        
          event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
       {
           return false;
       }
       if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
       {
            btnNught.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            //Set whatever color you want to set
       }
       else 
       {

       }
       return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, on what conditions could you get to the btnNught.setPressed(true); in the second example? As I see, you simply can't press the button. On Action Down you consume the action, so button won't be pressed.

**Edit:** Put a breakpoint at the start of listener and enter it in the different variants of the button use. And check the behaviour.

Comment: I want to create button like as ToglleButton with two state. Pressed and 'normal', non pressed state, with two different colors.

Comment: And is it pressed when you don't hear anything? look edited answer.

Comment: Oh, one more question: When it should make noises? On the change of the button states or on change to pressed or during all pressed state? Pls, put it in question.

Comment: And is the button getting the pressed state? Have you put the breakpoint at the start of listener? Doesn't it work twice by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"` to your `<Button>` tag.

Comment: is the same like before. no sound.

Comment: Are you hearing sounds from other apps? Could it be as simple as your volume level settings? An app cannot make sounds if the settings don't allow it.

Comment: At first I thought it might be a problem. But within other applications sound is heard

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear over when you want to play the sound but I am answering your question assuming that you wanna play it when the Action_DOWN occurs.If you plan to create a toggle button your code should look something like this

```
btnNught.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||        
               event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
       {
             return false;
       }
       if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
       {
          btnNught.setPressed(true);
          //Set whatever color you want to set

       }
       else 
       {
          btnNught.setPressed(false);
       }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited my question. I hope that now question is precisely :)

Answer (score 0):

Following line will play the click sound:

```
btnNught.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to listen sound

1 use inbuilt sound

```
Go to Settings -> Sound -> 
And do the following settings 

sound profile set **Normal**
Touch sound set **ON**
```

1. use custom sound

   play the user defined sound